# how to generate sequence id in composite primary with @IdClass in springboot hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, autogeneratecolumn

I am implementing a composite primary key with auto-generated annotation in spring boot hibernate. below is the scenario:

1. Account table has below columns:
   `stateCode,branchCode,prodCode,subProdCode,accountNumber`

whenever there is a change in stateCode,branchCode,prodCode,subProdCode , the table Account should have new accountNumber .

eg:

```
stateCode,branchCode,prodCode,subProdCode,accountNumber
11,01,20,1,00001 
11,01,30,1,00001  (there is a change in prodCode) 
11,01,30,2,00001  (there is a change in subprodcode)
11,01,20,2,00001  (there is a change in prod & subprodcode)
11,01,20,1,00002  (prodcode,subprod code has already account number 00001 , 
                       now it should be 00002)
```

the same question is already posted at [Sequences with composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060469/sequences-with-composite-primary-key)
but i would like to know , if there is any new feature introduced in the latest version of spring boot hibernate.

Below is the code , which i have implemented:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@IdClass(CompositeId.class)
public class CompositeAccountNumber {
    private String city;
    private String custName;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long accNumber;
    @Id
    private String stateCode;
    @Id
    private String branchCode;
    @Id
    private String prodCode;
    @Id
    private String subProdCode;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class CompositeId  implements Serializable {
    private String stateCode;
    private String branchCode;
    private String prodCode;
    private String subProdCode;
    private Long accNumber;
}
```

I am getting below result with above code:

```
stateCode,branchCode,prodCode,subProdCode,accountNumber
11,01,20,1,00001 
11,01,30,1,00002  
11,01,30,2,00003  
11,01,20,2,00004 
11,01,20,1,00005
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem in the current project But after spending a couple of hours. It worked for me and this would be helpful as well.

*Comment out the @**GenericGenerator** lines if it's not relevant for your scenario. ( in my case, GenericGenerator implementation class appending a string before inserting a Sequence in key field.)*

ClientEntity contains a composite primary key ( **manager_id + client_id** )

```
@Entity(name = "clientMaster")
@Table(name = "clientMaster")
@IdClass(ClientId.class)
public class ClientEntity implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Generated serial version UID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2716239938412051148L;


    @Id
    @Column(name = "client_id",length = 50,nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CLIENTMASTER_SEQ")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "CLIENTMASTER_SEQ",
            strategy = "com.abc.api.utils.StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "50"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "CNT"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%06d") })
    private String clientId;


    @Id
    @Column(name = "manager_id")
    private String managerId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    protected ManagerEntity manager;

    // Getter & Setter

   }
```

**ClientId - composite key entity.**

```
    public class ClientId implements Serializable {

        private String clientId;

        private String managerId;

        // Getter and Setter
    }
```

**And ManagerEntity -**

```
    @Entity(name = "portfolioManager")
    @Table(name = "portfolio_manager")
    public class ManagerEntity implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "manager_id",length = 50,nullable = false)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PORTFOLIO_MANAGER_SEQ")
        @GenericGenerator(
                name = "PORTFOLIO_MANAGER_SEQ",
                strategy = "com.abc.api.utils.StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator",
                parameters = {
                        @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "50"),
                        @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "MNG"),
                        @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%06d") })

        private String managerId;

@Column(name = "manager_name",length = 100)
private String managerName;

 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "manager")
 protected List<ClientEntity> clients = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: This example really helped me. I was struggling with the correct way to do this type of mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`@GenericGenerator`](https://thoughts-on-java.org/custom-sequence-based-idgenerator/), it essentially allows you to access both the entity instance and the Hibernate's `Session` when generating sequence values. This way, you can query the table for the existence of the combination of the other (non-generated) keys you're about to insert and act accordingly.